# Add a leading zero to months less than 10 and trim 4 digit years to 2 digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to print manipulate month and string which I fetch from a table and display in the format like '12/20', '11/20', 09/20'

For this I need to trim the last 2 digits from year and also a leading zero to months which are less than 10.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(MONTH(O.AddDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(O.AddDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS TimeStamp
FROM 
    [Order] O
WHERE 
    O.CountryCode = 9009
GROUP BY 
    CAST(MONTH(O.AddDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(O.AddDate) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

This provided output in the format of '10/2020', '8/2020' but I require it to be like '08/20', '10/20'

Comment: You're reintroducing the Y2K bug, in the very year that Lloyd's and RBS crashed because of this

Comment: And at a minimum, every programmer should know how to use modulo. Here you can also apply the RIGHT function to grab the last 2 characters (as ill-advised as that is).

Comment: that is bad idea to format column inside the sql directly. so the database can not replacable. but for bi or sql reports that is okey, and you can simply use string function also date function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `format()`:

```
select format(O.AddDate, 'MM/yy') as timestamp
from [Order] o
group by format(O.AddDate, 'MM/yy')
```

Obviously that's not your entire query; otherwise, if you have no aggregation function in the `select` clause, you can use `select distinct` instead of `group by`.

Comment: 2-digit years. Lloyd's and RBS crashing in January because of it. I really, really, really don't like this

Comment: i have aggregation in my select clause, the format is giving error of aggregate and group by clause

Comment: @Jazz: this query would not raise that type of error. You must be running something different.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO formatting dates is a presentation layer concern. SQL Server should provide the data and presentation layer should show the data to user as required. So I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    YEAR(O.AddDate) AS AddDateYear, MONTH(O.AddDate) AS AddDateMonth
FROM 
    [Order] O
WHERE 
    O.CountryCode = 9009
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(O.AddDate) AS AddDateYear, MONTH(O.AddDate) AS AddDateMonth
FROM 
    [Order] O
WHERE 
    O.CountryCode = 9009
GROUP BY
   YEAR(O.AddDate), MONTH(O.AddDate)
```

However, if you insist in formatting the date like you requested, then here is the query:

```
SELECT
   RIGHT('0' + CAST(T.AddDateMonth AS varchar(2)), 2) + '/'
   + RIGHT(CAST(T.AddDateYear) AS varchar(4), 2) AS Y2kVulnerableTimestamp
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        YEAR(O.AddDate) AS AddDateYear, MONTH(O.AddDate) AS AddDateMonth
    FROM 
        [Order] O
    WHERE 
        O.CountryCode = 9009
) T
```